# Spark parameter is not working in SparkSubmitOperator - AirFlow

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, airflow, spark-submit

I have passed below spark parameters in conf in Spark Submit Operator but it looks like those are not working while running the job.

```
my_conf = {
        'spark.io.compression.codec' : 'snappy',
        'spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.size' : '30000',
        'spark.yarn.queue' : 'pixel',
        'spark.driver.cores' : '5',
        'spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors' : '100',
        'spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors' : '300',
        'spark.shuffle.compress' : 'false',
        'spark.sql.tungsten.enabled' : 'true',
        'spark.shuffle.spill' : 'true',
        'spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec' : 'snappy',
        'spark.speculation' : 'true',
        'spark.kryo.referenceTracking' : 'false',
        'spark.hadoop.parquet.block.size' : '134217728',
        'spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version' : '2',
        'spark.executor.memory' : '22g',
        'spark.hadoop.dfs.blocksize' : '134217728',
        'spark.shuffle.manager' : 'sort',
        'spark.driver.memory' : '25g',
        'spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.minsize' : '134217728',
        'spark.akka.frameSize' : '1024',
        'spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead' : '3120',
        'spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown' : 'true',
        'spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed' : 'true',
        'spark.hadoop.parquet.enable.summary-metadata' : 'false',
        'spark.serializer' : 'org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer',
        'spark.rdd.compress' : 'true',
        'spark.task.maxFailures' : '50',
        'spark.yarn.max.executor.failures' : '30',
        'spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts' : '1',
        'spark.default.parallelism' : '2001',
        'spark.network.timeout' : '1200s',
        'spark.hadoop.dfs.client.read.shortcircuit' : 'true',
        'spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled' : 'true',
        'spark.executor.cores' : '5',
        'spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead' : '5025',
        'spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles' : 'true',
        'spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema' : 'false',
        'spark.sql.avro.compression.codec' : 'snappy',
        'spark.hadoop.dfs.domain.socket.path' : '/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/dn_socket',
        'spark.shuffle.spill.compress' : 'false',
        'spark.sql.caseSensitive' : 'true',
        'spark.hadoop.mapreduce.use.directfileoutputcommitter' : 'true',
        'spark.shuffle.service.enabled' : 'true',
        'spark.driver.maxResultSize' : '0',
        'spark.sql.shuffle.partitions' : '2001'}
```

Below is the class which is used in AirFlow to run spark job

```
SparkSubmitOperator(
                                 task_id='ml_agg',
                                 application='/home/hdfs/airflow/dags/ML_Agg/ML_Aggregation-assembly-1.0.jar',
                                 conf=my_conf,
                                 conn_id='spark_default',
                 files=None,
                 py_files=None,
                 archives=None,
                 driver_class_path=None,
                 jars=None,
                 java_class='com.pubmatic.ml.MLAggregation_v2',
                 packages='com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0,com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:2.0.1',
                 exclude_packages=None,
                 repositories=None,
                 keytab=None,
                 principal=None,
                 name='test_airflow_ml_aggregation',
                 application_args=application_args,
                 env_vars=None,
                 verbose=False,
                 spark_binary="spark-submit",
                 dag=my_dag
                 )
```

Also, mentioning the spark_default configuration.

```
{"queue":"default","deploy_mode": "cluster", "spark_home": "", "spark_binary": "spark-submit", "namespace": "default"}
```

Still, the job is running on **default** queue on yarn.

Should I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

The `spark.yarn.queue` is commented out. You need to uncomment it to run it in `Pixel` queue.

To use the queue in the spark-submit you can run the `spark-submit` command as below:-

```
spark-submit --master yarn --conf spark.executor.memory=XG --conf spark.driver.memory=YG --packages [packages separated by ,] --queue [queue_name] --class [class_name] [jar_file] [arguments]
```

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo. It's not commented actually. I've tried to make it bold that's why it's showing like that.

Comment: ```'spark.io.compression.codec':'snappy' 
       'spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.size':'30000'
       'spark.yarn.queue':'pixel'
       'spark.driver.cores':'5' 
       'spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors':'200' 
       'spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors':'350' ```

Comment: Can you edit your question with the details of the spark submit and the spark-default.conf so that we get more context.

Comment: Updated the description.